# How to determine the biggest float value (in terms of used bytes) with SQL in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g, oracle-10g-r2

I would like to know how to check out what is the biggest float value in terms of used bytes in a specific column.

Oracle DB Version is 10.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[VSIZE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions213.htm)

> VSIZE returns the number of bytes in the internal representation of
>   expr.

`select max(vsize(mycolumn)) from mytable;`

Comment: How can I output the actual value of the biggest float value? When I use the statement above it will - of course, as desired - show me e.g. 10 Bytes, but I would like to know what inserted value is responsible for this size.

I used `Select * from TABLE where COLUMN = (Select max(vsize(COLUMN)) from TABLE);` but it still shows me the Byte size instead of the actual value.

Comment: Use `select * from TABLE where vsize(COLUMN) = (select max(vsize(COLUMN)) from TABLE);`

Comment: BTW, Oracle uses a floating point decimal notation for the numbers. So the number of bytes occupied by a number is proportional to the number of significant decimal digits in that number. Numbers 1, 10, 1000, 100000 all have the same size: 2 bytes. Number 1.000000000001 however needs 8 bytes.

Comment: @AlbertGodfrind Thank you for both comments! I also discovered the `WITH ... AS` Statement which also worked for me:  `WITH CUSTOM AS (
  SELECT COLUMN, VSIZE (COLUMN) AS BYTE FROM TABLE) Select * from CUSTOM where Byte > 8;`